# How to redirect with an addFlash from a class that implements Symfony 4 UserCheckerInterface

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I need your help. I set up an account activation system by email address that works very well.

Currently, I manage to refuse access but I do not know how to do a redirection with an `addFlash` and not display the 403 pass.

You'll have an idea of ​​how I could do that?

Here is how I deny access, I use the `UserChecker`.

```
class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    /**
     * Checks the user account before authentication.
     *
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return RedirectResponse
     */
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if ($user->getIsActivated() === null || $user->getIsActivated() === false) {
            throw new HttpException(403, 'Access denied.');
        } else {
            return new RedirectResponse('account_login');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throw exception that extends AccountStatusException froum your UserCheckerInterface. E.g.:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException;

// ...
throw new DisabledException('User account is disabled.');
```

And listen to that exception as follows:

```
// src/EventSubscriber/ExceptionSubscriber.php
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class ExceptionSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /**
     * @var FlashBagInterface
     */
    private $flashBag;

    /**
     * @var UrlGeneratorInterface
     */
    private $router;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session, UrlGeneratorInterface $router) 
    {
        $this->flashBag = $session->getFlashBag();
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        // return the subscribed events, their methods and priorities
        return [
            KernelEvents::EXCEPTION => 'onException',
        ];
    }

    public function onException(ExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // You get the exception object from the received event
        $exception = $event->getException();

        if (!$exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            return;
        }

        $this->flashBag->add(
            'warning',
            $exception->getMessage()
        );

        $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('homepage'));
        $event->setResponse($response);     
    }
}
```

If you use default services.yaml, this is enough.

More info about event subscribers: 
https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#creating-an-event-subscriber

Comment: how do I use it in my UserChecker? By `Injection ?`

Comment: No. Throw AccesDeniedException instead of HttpException. Symfony will catch it and trigger your AccessDeniedHandler instead of 403 response.

Comment: It does not work.
`if ($user->getIsActivate() === null || $user->getIsActivate() === false) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException();
        } else {
            return new RedirectResponse('account_login');
        }`

Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException::setToken() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface, null given, called in /var/www/symfony/vendor/symfony/security-http/Firewall/ExceptionListener.php on line 130

Comment: Sorry my bad. User has not authentication token before authentication.  AccessDeniedException assumes that you are denying access to authenticated user without privileges. I edited my answer to use suitable exception.

Comment: But it does not pass in the `onException()` function

Comment: $exception sadly does not have a setResponse Method

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it. $event has setResponse.